# codemodel narrow for generics

Tags: java, generics, sun-codemodel

I would like to generate a new class as follows:

```
public class QueryBuilder_QueryField
extends AbstractQueryBuilder<QueryBuilder_QueryField>
```

and i tried this but it doesn't narrow the extends...

```
JCodeModel model = new JCodeModel();
String fqcn = packageName + "." + className;
JDefinedClass builderClass = model._class(fqcn);
builderClass._extends(AbstractQueryBuilder.class).narrow(builderClass);
```

but instead ends up like

```
public class QueryBuilder_QueryField
extends AbstractQueryBuilder
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to narrow before you pass the class into `_extends()`:

```
JCodeModel model = new JCodeModel();
String fqcn = packageName + "." + className;
JDefinedClass builderClass = model._class(fqcn);
builderClass._extends(model.ref(AbstractQueryBuilder.class).narrow(builderClass));
```

Generates:

```
public class QueryBuilder_QueryField
extends AbstractQueryBuilder<QueryBuilder_QueryField>
```

Comment: That worked!  thanks John.  could u 1+ my question.  i'm new here and need some reputation apparently :)  i can't even 1+ your answer in recognition!